# Modify element attribute from key in array in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to modify/replace the value of an element attribute (`<channel id="">`), in this way:

From:

```
<tv generator-info-name="musor.tv">
  <channel id="AMC">
    <display-name lang="hu">AMC (HD)</display-name>
    <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/AMC</url>
    <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/amc.png"/>
  </channel>
  <channel id="ANIMAL">
    <display-name lang="hu">Animal Planet (HD)</display-name>
    <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/ANIMAL</url>
    <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/animalplanet_hd.jpg"/>
  </channel>
</tv>
```

To:

```
<tv generator-info-name="musor.tv">
  <channel id="AMC Hungary">
    <display-name lang="hu">AMC (HD)</display-name>
    <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/AMC</url>
    <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/amc.png"/>
  </channel>
  <channel id="ANIMAL Planet">
    <display-name lang="hu">Animal Planet (HD)</display-name>
    <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/ANIMAL</url>
    <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/animalplanet_hd.jpg"/>
  </channel>
</tv>
```

From/To values should be stored in something like an array, if this is possible in XSLT:

```
AMC => AMC Hungary,
ANIMAL => ANIMAL Planet
```

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

As a convenient solution I suggest to create a third XML file containing the transformations.

Here, I call it `trans.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<replacements>
  <FromTo from="AMC" to="AMC Hungary" />
  <FromTo from="ANIMAL" to="ANIMAL Planet" />
</replacements>
```

To make use of it, the following XSLT file first performs an *Identity Transform* and then replaces the `@id` attributes according to the `trans.xml` file (I hope this is close enough to an array):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:variable name="transformations" select="document('trans.xml')" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">          <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="channel/@id">        <!-- replacing attribute values -->
    <xsl:variable name="cur" select="." />  <!-- save value of @id -->
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="$transformations/replacements/FromTo[@from = $cur]/@to" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `xsl:choose` instruction as the "array":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="channel/@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". = 'AMC'">AMC Hungary</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". = 'ANIMAL'">ANIMAL Planet</xsl:when>
            <!-- etc. -->
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> From/To values should be stored in an array, if this is possible in
>   XSLT:
>
> AMC => AMC Hungary,
>
> ANIMAL => ANIMAL Planet

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="pMapping">
  <rep old="AMC" new="AMC Hungary"/>
  <rep old="ANIMAL" new="ANIMAL Planet"/>
 </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="channel/@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/xsl:param/rep[@old=current()]/@new"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied** on the provided XML document:

```
<tv generator-info-name="musor.tv">
  <channel id="AMC">
    <display-name lang="hu">AMC (HD)</display-name>
    <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/AMC</url>
    <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/amc.png"/>
  </channel>
  <channel id="ANIMAL">
    <display-name lang="hu">Animal Planet (HD)</display-name>
    <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/ANIMAL</url>
    <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/animalplanet_hd.jpg"/>
  </channel>
</tv>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tv generator-info-name="musor.tv">
   <channel id="AMC Hungary">
      <display-name lang="hu">AMC (HD)</display-name>
      <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/AMC</url>
      <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/amc.png"/>
   </channel>
   <channel id="ANIMAL Planet">
      <display-name lang="hu">Animal Planet (HD)</display-name>
      <url>http://musor.tv/mai/tvmusor/ANIMAL</url>
      <icon src="http://musor.tv/images/animalplanet_hd.jpg"/>
   </channel>
</tv>
```

**Note**:

1. The mapping in the `<xsl:param>` can be specified externally by the invoker of the transformation (on the command-line or within the invoking code) because this is a *global* `<xsl:param>` declaration. *In fact this is the only solution of the three that allows an unknown at compile-time mapping to be used in the transformation*. One could pass as the parameter a string that is an URI (incuding a file:// uri) to a separate XML document(s) where the mapping is located. With either the former or the latter, this allows to add new mappings or modify mappings, without touching the transformation.
2. I strongly recommend to try to avoid using XSLT conditional instructions, such as `<xsl:if>`, `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>` ... etc. Using these often leads to convoluted, not easily understandable, spaghetti-like code and is an anti-pattern in both procedural/imperative and declarative/functional programming styles.